# 301 redirect help needed for urls with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

How do I 301 redirect all urls such as

http://domain.com/languages/italian/itemlist.feed?start=[0-9]&format=feed
http://domain.com/languages/italian/itemlist.feed?format=feed&type=rss

to

http://domain.com/languages/italian.html

Theses errors occurred when web developers put the wrong DB onto a live site and showing in web master tools

Hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=[0-9]*&format=feed [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=feed&type=rss
RewriteRule ^/?languages/italian/itemlist.feed$ /languages/italian.html [L,R=301]
```

If you need to add these rules to the "languages" directory then it'll need to look a little different:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=[0-9]*&format=feed [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=feed&type=rss
RewriteRule ^italian/itemlist.feed$ /languages/italian.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)start=[0-9]($|&)
>
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)format=feed($|&)
>
> RewriteRule ^languages/italian/itemlist.feed$ /languages/italian.html?[L,R=301]
>
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)format=feed($|&)
>
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)type=rss($|&)
>
> RewriteRule ^languages/italian/itemlist.feed$ /languages/italian.html?[L,R=301]